# Prevent Birt from converting numbers

Tags: birt

I have a Birt report with a data set that has one computed column of the type "Java Object". This column takes it's input from the surrounding application as a Java object and later uses this exact object to calculate something.

The computed column's expression:

```
var result;
try {
    result = application.getValueFromApplication(row["id"]);
} catch (err) {
    Packages.java.lang.System.out.println("Error getting value " + row["id"] + ": " + err);
    result = null;
}
```

However... there seems to be a bug that Birt converts these values to JavaScript values. That's stupid in the best case, but it gets even worse for numbers. Because ***all*** numbers are converted to the same stupid JavaScript "number" type. Yes, even `BigDecimal`and `Long`.

So in the above example, `getValueFromApplication()` returns a `BigDecimal`, while result is a Javascript `number` one.

When the time comes to start the calculation, all these values are internally converted back to `Double`, and now the calculation fails because it requires the value to be what the application gave the report.

So somewhere there is this snippet:

```
application.doMagic(row["value"]);
```

Where Birt tries to force it's `Double` down the method's throat, even though it had a `BigDecimal` in the beginning.

How do I prevent Birt from mindlessly converting numbers to some JavaScript blob instead of using the concrete Java class?

Comment: You should share your code if you want meaningful input. Take a look at this... maybe it can help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html

Comment: @Jeroen I'm not sure how the code is supposed to help, but I added some. In my case I don't know the concrete Java class. I only know `getValueFromApplication` returns the exact class `doMagic` needs.